How to use VertexAIModelGarden in langchain?
I am trying to call the llama 3 model using langchain and vertex AI model garden.
from langchain_google_vertexai import VertexAIModelGarden
llm = VertexAIModelGarden (project-project_name, endpoint_id=endpoint_id, location=location)
llm.invoke(prompt)

Above code is working fine but I want to give temperature,max token parameters to control the output.
llm = VertexAIModelGarden(
  project="YOUR PROJECT", 
  endpoint_id="YOUR ENDPOINT_ID", 
  location=location, 
  allowed_model_args=["max_tokens", "temperature"], stop_sequences=["</eot_id/>"])
prompt = "What is the meaning of Life?"
llm(prompt,1024,0.2)

I tried using above code but getting an error that float object has no attribute handlers.
Also trying to give prompt with system instruction like below
sys_prompt = ""
user_input = ""
prompt_template=F"""<|begin_of_text|></start_header_id|>system<|end_header_id|>\n\n{sys_prompt]<|eot_id/></ start_header_id >user<|end_header_id>{user_input}<|eot_id/></start_header_id/>assistant</ end_header_id/>"""
